# Change credentials per server?

Tags: opshub

I've installed opshub on my pc that is on domain ABC.  I have succesfully migrated projects from a TFS server on domain ABC to visual studio online.  Now I've added a TFS server that is in domain DEF and it doesn't ask me for credentials for that server.  I just get a blank collection list, I think its trying to use my current credentials from domain ABC.  How can I get it to ask me for the credentials to domain DEF when trying to access that server?

Answer (score 0):

User level authentication details are stored inside Team Foundation cache directory under following locations. If you have already authenticated for the TFS server then details for that server is stored inside cache directory. This won't ask you credentials again while you are doing next migration.

If you want to authenticate with the new credentials for different domain you need to clear data from the following directories.

C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Make sure original folders remains there (Cache). Just remove contents of those directories. Also make sure you close all the applications which uses TFS cache like visual studio, opshub migration utility.

Answer (score 0):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server.aspx for correct answer. It worked for me.

Comment: You should include the relevant details of the link in your answer.